# R object identification

Tags: r, object

I am often ending up with a function producing output for which I don't understand the output data type. I'm expecting a list and it ends up being a list of lists or a data frame or something else. What's a good method or workflow for figuring out the output data type when first using a function?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I usually start out with some combination of:

```
typeof(obj)
class(obj)
sapply(obj, class)
sapply(obj, attributes)
attributes(obj)
names(obj)
```

as appropriate based on what's revealed.  For example, try with:

```
obj <- data.frame(a=1:26, b=letters)
obj <- list(a=1:26, b=letters, c=list(d=1:26, e=letters))
data(cars)
obj <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)
```

..etc.

If `obj` is an S3 or S4 object, you can also try `methods` or `showMethods`, `showClass`, etc.  Patrick Burns' [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) has a pretty good section on this (sec #7).

**EDIT**: Dirk and Hadley mention `str(obj)` in their answers.  It really is much better than any of the above for a quick and even detailed peek into an object.

Comment: i don't think I made it that far through R Inferno. Thanks for sending me back there.

Comment: In case you haven't seen it already, "S4 objects in 15 pages or less" [ http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/S-Workshop/Gentleman/S4Objects.pdf ] is another good read (with more details).

Comment: I had not see that. Thanks for the link. That was worth the price of admission. :)

Comment: I've created a little utility function that encodes this suggestion. See [tellMeAboutThis.r](https://github.com/eludom/r/blob/master/utils/tellMeAbout.r)

Answer (score 69):

```
str(x)
```

It's all you need to remember for 99% of cases.

Comment: ``str(x, max.level=1)`` can be useful if x is a multi-layered ggplot!

Comment: str(UCTURE) hard to remember, 'cause I keep thinking "string" but oh, so useful. Will just have to say strUCTURE ten times.

Comment: if I have `str(x)` returning `Named num [1:10] 1.555 8.424 .... -attr(*,"names")= chr [1:10] "x1" "x2" ...`  what does that mean?   Is this an atomic vector with names?

Comment: more generally, how do I know if an object is a matrix, dataframe, etc?  `str()` does not seem to expose this.

Answer (score 13):

If I get 'someObject', say via

```
someObject <- myMagicFunction(...)
```

then I usually proceed by

```
class(someObject)
str(someObject)
```

which can be followed by head(), summary(), print(), ... depending on the class you have.

Comment: Just tried str(obj).  Way more than I expected from a string representation; very neat!  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
attributes(someObject)
```

Can also be useful