# Check if a variable is xts or data.frame

Tags: r, types, dataframe, xts

Well the question says it all..I want to check in one of my functions if a function parameter given is of xts or data frame type. How can I do this?

Comment: class(YourX) is one way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855589/a-comprehensive-survey-of-the-types-of-things-in-r-mode-and-class-and-type,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/r-types-and-classes-of-variables,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177926/r-object-identification,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125222/determine-the-data-types-of-an-r-data-frames-columns

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is a general practice to add `is.smth` and `as.smth` functions for these types of checks and conversions:

```
df <- data.frame()
xt <- xts()
is.data.frame(df)
[1] TRUE
is.data.frame(xt)
[1] FALSE
is.xts(df)
[1] FALSE
is.xts(xt)
[1] TRUE
```