# how to determine class of an object

Tags: r, oop

Note- The related question does not explain why `attr(myVar, "class")` returns `NULL` but not `list` (and why `class(myVar)` returns `list`).  What is the stander way in R to check the class of an object?

How do I find out if an object is "my custom class" or is a "list" of "my custom class" objects?

```
foo <- function(x) {
  a=list(x=x)
  attr(a, "class") <- "myclass"
  return(a)
}

newVar = list(foo(10),foo(20))
```

Now I want to find out what class of `newVar` .

```
attr(newVar, "class")  # NULL, but not list!
#NULL

##however this works fine
attr(newVar[[1]], "class")
#[1] "myclass"
```

Why is it so? What is the **correct** way to determine class in R?

Comment: Jut try `class(newVar)`

Comment: `class(newVar)` gives `list`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R object identification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177926/r-object-identification)

Comment: Can you please explane what is the difference between `attr(myVar, "class")` and `class(myVar)` and when should we use what ?

Comment: Se might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046953/why-is-namesx-better-than-attrx-names

Comment: @Pascal this makes me more confuse!!! what is the difference between "attr", "class" and "name" ?? What is the stander way ?

Comment: `?attr`, `?class`, `?name`

Comment: @Pascal I have already looked at the documentation but can't figure out the difference, that is why I am posting the question. My question basically boils down to why `attr(myVar, "class")` returns `NULL` but not `list`. The related question does not explain this. And also what is the stander way in R to check the class of an object?

Comment: Try running `attributes(newVar)` and you'll see that `newVar` has no attributes.  This is why `attr(newVar, "class")` returns `NULL`; there is nothing else to return.  If I were to try to pin any explanation for why a list has not attributes, I'd probably say it's because they are intended to be amorphous.  Almost anything in R that isn't a list is really just a list that has a class attribute (in other words, a special case of a list).

Comment: `list` is an implicit class. For explicit classes the class ID is given as an attribute (as are names and a lot of other stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "correct way" to determine the S3 class of an object is using function `class`.

Implicit classes:

```
class(list(1))
#[1] "list"
class(1:5)
#[1] "integer"
```

Explicit classes:

```
class(list(1))
class(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris))
#[1] "lm"

x <- 1:5
class(x) <- "myclass"
class(x)
#[1] "myclass"
```

Since a list can contain anything, you have to loop through it to find out the classes of the objects inside it, e.g., `sapply(yourlist, class)`.

The class ID is stored as an attribute (as are names, dimensions and some other stuff), but usually you don't need to worry about such internals, since R offers accessor functions.